# Schedule Einstein Chatbot Activation

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, einstein, einstein-chatbot

I want to activate Einstein chatbot at certain hours, like i want to automate the activation of it.
For example, Schedule activation each day at 6AM to 6PM. How can i do that?